# MVC Facebook application - dual template

Tags: facebook, iframe-app

Maybe this is a stupid question and I did not understand exactly how Facebook applications work but here it goes

I want to implement a small e-shop as a Facebook application and for the products to have like button. The application will be instaled on a business page.

The problem is that the link for the like post on the wall will be to the actual eshop not to the facebook application on the business page.(or is it possible to make it to the application (eg. when you click the browser goes to the business page, selects the eshop tab, opens the product)?)

So actually I need to make a eshop site with 2 templates one for outside view and one for IFrame facebook view.

Is it possible to detect (from code-behind not in javascript) If the request is from the iframe or directly from outside?

Or the solution is more simple.. create a small version of the shop for browsing products only to be viewed in facebook and a full shop for outside view and the only relation between them is that when you click the like post from the first one you go to the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution...
I have created 2 domains that point to the eshop
shop.domainname & facebook.shop.domainname.
And in code behind I can check the Request.Url.Host if it starts with facebook.
For the facebook app the canvas url will be with facebook.shop.domainname and the links from the like button will be for the shop.domainname.
In this way I should be able to use 2 templates for the site and detect witch one I shoul use....